# Create a subset of a table to send as an email attachment

Tags: excel, vba, email, ms-access, attachment

I need to create an Excel attachment specific to a subset of a table.

As the code loops through each sales rep (in this case), they would get an email with information pertinent to them in the email body, but also an Excel spreadsheet with the same information included in a bulk manner, sorted by status.

I'm thinking this would be done by creating a temporary table or something like that and clearing it out.

Here's what I have. Basically everything set up to put it on the email with categories and stuff.

```
Function SendNotification()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim sql, sMsg, sPrevTerritory, sPrevEmail, sCurrentTerritory, sPrevRep, sCurrentRep, sKrullj1, sImgPath, sTherapy As String
Dim iNotRecieved, iCompleted, iWorksheetGenerated, iReconciled As Integer

iNotRecieved = 0
iCompleted = 0
iWorksheetGenerated = 0
iReconciled = 0
sKrullj1 = "john.m.krull@placeofemployment.com"

'Set Outlook Variables
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Set db = CurrentDb
sql = "select * from [MT + Emails] Order By Territory,[Status] desc where Therapy = 'Peripheral' and [Loc Type] = 'Account'"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

sPrevTerritory = rs!Territory
sPrevRep = rs![Employee Name]
sPrevEmail = Nz(rs![Employee Email Address], GetUserName() & "@placeofemployment.com")
sTherapy = rs!Therapy

sMsg = "Hello," & vbLf & vbLf & "Here is an update on your Cycle Count(s)." & vbLf & vbLf

Do While Not rs.EOF

    If sPrevTerritory <> rs!Territory Then
        sMsg = sMsg & "Regards," & vbLf & vbLf & "Customer Care"

        With OutMail
            .To = sPrevEmail
            '.To = sKrullj1
            .BCC = GetUserName() & "@placeofemployment.com"
            .Sentonbehalfofname = "Is10amTooEarlyForLunch@placeofemployment.com"
            '.Subject = "Cycle Count Update"
            .Subject = "Cycle Count Update - " & sPrevTerritory & "" & sPrevRep
            .Body = sMsg
            .Send
            '.Display
        End With
        
        sMsg = "Hello," & vbLf & vbLf & "Here is an update on your Cycle Count(s)." & vbLf & vbLf
        sPrevEmail = Nz(rs![Employee Email Address], GetUserName() & "@placeofemployment.com")
        sPrevTerritory = rs!Territory
        sPrevRep = rs![Employee Name]
        iNotRecieved = 0
        iCompleted = 0
        iWorksheetGenerated = 0
        iReconciled = 0

    End If

    sCurrentEmail = Nz(rs![Employee Email Address], GetUserName() & "@placeofemployment.com")
    If rs![Status] = "Not Recieved" And iNotRecieved = 0 Then
        iNotRecieved = 1
        sMsg = sMsg & "The following Cycle Count (s) have not been received:" & vbLf & vbLf
    ElseIf rs![Status] = "Completed" And iCompleted = 0 Then
        iCompleted = 1
        sMsg = sMsg & "The following Cycle Count(s) have been completed:" & vbLf & vbLf
    ElseIf rs![Status] = "Worksheet Generated" And iWorksheetGenerated = 0 Then
        iWorksheetGenerated = 1
        sMsg = sMsg & "The following Cycle Count(s) have been receieved and are pending reconciliation:" & vbLf & vbLf
    ElseIf rs![Status] = "Reconcilied - Pending SAP Processing" And iReconciled = 0 Then
        iReconciled = 1
        sMsg = sMsg & "The following Cycle Count(s) have been recieved, reconciled, and are pending SAP processing:" & vbLf & vbLf
    End If
    
    sMsg = sMsg & vbTab & "Status: " & rs![Status] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "Location: " & rs![Location] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "Location Name: " & rs![Location Name] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "Territory: " & rs![Territory Name] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "District: " & rs![District Name] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "CC Master ID: " & rs![ID] & vbLf & vbLf _

    rs.MoveNext
    
Loop

sMsg = sMsg & "Regards," & vbLf & vbLf & "Customer Care"

With OutMail
    .To = sPrevEmail
    '.To = sKrullj1
    .BCC = GetUserName() & "@placeofemployment.com"
    .Sentonbehalfofname = "ImStarving@shouldhaveeatenbreakfast.com"
    '.Subject = "Cycle Count Update"
    .Subject = "Cycle Count Update - " & sPrevTerritory & "" & sRep
    .Body = sMsg
    .Send
    '.Display
End With

' Reset Outlook variables
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this by creating another query that uses the territory from the record set to limit the results, then attached that.

```
Function SendNotificationNVA()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim sql, sMsg, sPrevTerritory, sPrevEmail, sTerritory, sPrevTName, sTName, sKrullj1, sImgPath, sTherapy, sLocType As String
Dim iNotRecieved, iCompleted, iWorksheetGenerated, iReconciled As Integer
Dim sFileName, sQuery, sExportFile, sTempFilePath, sCurrentEmail, sEndDate As String

iNotRecieved = 0
iCompleted = 0
iWorksheetGenerated = 0
iReconciled = 0
sKrullj1 = "john.m.krull@job.com"


'Set Outlook Variables
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set db = CurrentDb
sql = "select * from [Pending CC Notification Recipients - NVA] Order By Territory"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

sPrevTerritory = rs!Territory
sPrevTName = rs![Territory Name]
sLocType = rs![Loc Type]
sTherapy = rs!Therapy
sPrevEmail = Nz(rs![Employee Email Address], GetUserName() & "@job.com")
sTerritory = rs!Territory
sTName = rs![Territory Name]
sEndDate = rs![End Date]

sMsg = "Hello," & vbLf & vbLf & "Here is an update on your Cycle Count(s)." & vbLf & vbLf

Do While Not rs.EOF

    If sPrevTerritory <> rs!Territory Then

    sTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

    ' Setup parameters for export
        sql = "Delete * From [Pending CC Notification Parameter]"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql
        sql = "Insert Into [Pending CC Notification Parameter] ([Therapy],[Loc Type],[Territory],[Territory Name]) " _
            & "VALUES ('" & sTherapy & "','" & sLocType & "','" & sTerritory & "', '" & sTName & "')"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql

    ' Export data to attachment
        sFileName = sTName & " " & sTherapy
        sQuery = "MT + Emails"
        sExportFile = sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MT + Emails", _
            sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx", True

        sMsg = sMsg & "Regards," & vbLf & vbLf & "Customer Care"

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = sPrevEmail
            '.To = sKrullj1
            .BCC = GetUserName() & "@job.com"
            .Sentonbehalfofname = "rs@job.com"
            '.Subject = "Cycle Count Update"
            .Subject = "Cycle Count Update - " & sTName & " " & sTherapy & " " & sLocType
            .Body = sMsg
            .Attachments.Add sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx"
            '.Send
            .Display
        End With

    ' Delete temp file
        If (Dir(sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx") <> "") Then
            Kill sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx"
        End If

        sMsg = "Hello," & vbLf & vbLf & "Here is an update on your Cycle Count(s)." & vbLf & vbLf
        sPrevEmail = Nz(rs![Employee Email Address], GetUserName() & "@job.com")
        sPrevTerritory = rs!Territory
        iNotRecieved = 0
        iCompleted = 0
        iWorksheetGenerated = 0
        iReconciled = 0

    End If

    sCurrentEmail = Nz(rs![Employee Email Address], GetUserName() & "@job.com")
    If rs![Status] = "Not Recieved" And iNotRecieved = 0 Then
        iNotRecieved = 1
        sMsg = sMsg & "The following Cycle Count (s) have not been received:" & vbLf & vbLf
    End If

    sMsg = sMsg & vbTab & "Status: " & rs![Status] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "Location: " & rs![Loc Number] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "Location Type: " & rs![Loc Type] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "Location Name: " & rs![Loc Name] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "Territory Name: " & rs![Territory Name] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "District Name: " & rs![District Name] & vbLf _
         & vbTab & "ID: " & rs![ID] & vbLf & vbLf _

    sTerritory = rs!Territory
    sTName = rs![Territory Name]

    rs.MoveNext

Loop


sMsg = sMsg & "Regards," & vbLf & vbLf & "Customer Care"

    sTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

    ' Setup parameters for export
        sql = "Delete * From [Pending CC Notification Parameter]"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql
        sql = "Insert Into [Pending CC Notification Parameter] ([Therapy],[Loc Type],[Territory],[Territory Name]) " _
            & "VALUES ('" & sTherapy & "','" & sLocType & "','" & sTerritory & "', '" & sTName & "')"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql

    ' Export data to attachment
        sFileName = sTName & " " & sTherapy
        sQuery = "MT + Emails"
        sExportFile = sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MT + Emails", _
            sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx", True

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = sPrevEmail
    '.To = sKrullj1
    .BCC = GetUserName() & "@job.com"
    .Sentonbehalfofname = "rs@job.com"
    '.Subject = "Cycle Count Update"
    .Subject = "Cycle Count Update - " & sTName & " " & sTherapy & " " & sLocType
    .Body = sMsg
    .Attachments.Add sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx"
    '.Send
    .Display

End With

    ' Delete temp file
        If (Dir(sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx") <> "") Then
            Kill sTempFilePath & sFileName & ".xlsx"
        End If

' Reset Outlook variables
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Function
```